# reverting back from https to http and google still displaying site as https

Tags: google

Our site was on a https connection but we are now back on a http connection.

I do not control the web host.

How can I get google to update and remove the link to the https version of the website?

I have been using the fetch as Google option to get Google to recrawl the site.

Ultimately this has to be fixed one way or another. Should I consider using use the remove URLs tool and pick the root URL?

Comment: Google will update it eventually. Just hang tight, this process may take a couple of days to "a while".

Comment: It's the same as going from http to https

Comment: Has the SSL cert already been removed and so these indexed URLs are resulting in errors?!

Comment: Yes - that's the issue - google is showing the site with the https link still.

Comment: Unfortunately that's kinda like shooting yourself in the foot - if you are wanting to maintain your ranking. The site migration should have occurred _before_ the security cert was removed. You need to follow the same procedure for a site migration (linked above), except you obviously can't redirect the old URLs. _Eventually_ Google will reindex your site.